# Как нажать на кнопку

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: Код кнопки]

Вопрос как кликнуть по кнопке с помощью selenium ?

Comment: Находите и кликаете.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще странный вопрос, изучите документацию по WebDriver для начала

Сам клик:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.bloko-link_dimmed').click();
```